# SWT Widgets are not displayed in the Wizard when the Dialog is opened

Tags: java, swt, wizard

I created a wizard with one page and has two widgets: a list and a button 
but when calling the wizard using `dialog.open()` the wizard opens but the widgets of the page are not displayed. I don't know what is wrong!

Here is the code of the page

```
public class SelectCriterionPage extends WizardPage  {

private Composite container;
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
List variables,selected;
protected SelectCriterionPage() {

super("CriterionSelection","SelectCriterionPage",null);

setTitle("Selection of criterion variables");



}
@Override

public void createControl(Composite parent) {

container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
variables=new List(container, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
//fill the list with variables
for(String item:listItems)
variables.add(item);

variables.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
Button btn=new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
btn.setText("<");
GridData gr=new GridData(GridData.FILL,SWT.CENTER);
btn.setLayoutData(gr);
setControl(container);

}
}
```

i called my wizard

```
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(null, new       SelectSlicingCriterionWizard());
dialog.open();
```

here is my wizard:

```
public class SelectSlicingCriterionWizard extends Wizard{
IWorkbenchPage workbench;
IStructuredSelection selection;
ArrayList<String> listItems;

 public SelectSlicingCriterionWizard() {

        super();

        setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);

      }


@Override
public boolean performFinish() {
    System.out.println("Finish clicked");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean performCancel(){
    return true;
}

 @Override

  public void addPages() {
     SelectCriterionPage criterionpage=new SelectCriterionPage();
     addPage(criterionpage);
 }
 @Override

  public String getWindowTitle() {

    return "Select Criterion Variables";

}
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection)
{
this.workbench=workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
this.selection=selection;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set a Layout for your wizard page `Composite`. Since you seem to be trying to use Grids this should be:

```
container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

container.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

Your `GridData` for the button is using the wrong constructor (the two parameter constructor sets the height and width). Use something like:

```
GridData gr = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, false);

btn.setLayoutData(gr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a Layout for your Composite.
For examples on using GridLayout please see - https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#gridlayout

For an example on using GridLayout in WizardPage, please see - http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/wizard/Snippet047WizardWithLongRunningOperation.java